# TCP server doesn't receive whole data

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I used Python and TCP connection to make a server that reads an image which is sent by a client. Then the server gets the colour code of it and sends the colour code back to the client.

Everything is working fine except that the server doesn't receive a full file (image in my case).

I suppose I can't get the loop to work because the server does receive the whole image if I change server.py script code (see the code below) from `img = connectionSocket.recv(2048)` to `img = connectionSocket.recv(200000)`

I want to make it work, so that the server receives the whole image without changing the buffer size in `recv()` function

Here are the scripts of client.py and server.py

**Client.py**

```
from socket import *
from PIL import Image

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5000

#cSocket - created client socket
#img - sent image to the server
#ccode - colour code of the colour in the image
cSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
cSocket.connect((IP,PORT))

with open ('Image.bmp','rb') as im:
    img = im.read()
cSocket.sendall(img)
print('Sent the image to the server..')
cCode=cSocket.recv(2048)

print('The colour code of the sent image is: ' + cCode.decode())
cSocket.close()
```

**Server.py**

```
from socket import *
from PIL import Image
import io
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5000

#sSocket - created server socket
#img - image received from the client
#cCode - colour code of the image
sSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sSocket.bind((IP,PORT))
sSocket.listen(1)

print ('The server is ready')

while 1:
    connectionSocket, addr = sSocket.accept()
    img = connectionSocket.recv(2048)
    if not img:
        break
    print (str(img))
    t_img = io.BytesIO(img)
    img = Image.open(t_img)
    cCode = img.getcolors(256)
    cCode = str(cCode)
    print (cCode)
    connectionSocket.send(cCode.encode())
    connectionSocket.close()
```

Comment: You have to run `recv()` multiple times until you have the full image part by part. It might be tricky to know when it is complete and you could need a simple protocol around it giving you the size to expect before.

Comment: I've just tried changing a part of server.py script. As you suggested, I have added a second loop around the `connectionSocket.recv(2048)` . However, it seems like there is something wrong with my if statement because the second loop never breaks (I checked that by adding print('receiving..') inside the second loop, also the client doesn't receive any messages, although it should after the second loop breaks). The changed part of the code looks like.._sorry, it doesn't allow me to post long messages_ , so here is https://pastebin.com/5TwpfG2q

Comment: Update.. I have changed the code, so that the server compares the value of received data size with client sent image size. Here is that bit of code: https://pastebin.com/9A5x5HFB _NOTE: the bytes_sent is the size of the image sent by client. It is len(img) on client side. This part of code works with no problem_

Comment: Update your question, not a pastebin link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a byte streaming protocol.  It has no concept of message boundaries, so you have to build in a protocol to determine if you have a complete message.  Since you send one data blob (a .BMP image), and receive one data blob (the color response), a simple protocol is:

1. Stream the .BMP to the socket.
2. Shutdown writing to the socket to indicate to the server the image is complete.
3. Server sends the response.
4. Server closes the socket indicating the response is complete.

Here's an implementation...

**client.py**

```
import socket
from PIL import Image

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5000

with socket.socket() as cSocket:
    cSocket.connect((IP,PORT))

    with open('Image.bmp','rb') as im:
        img = im.read()
    cSocket.sendall(img)
    cSocket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) # Indicate all data is sent

    print('Sent the image to the server..')

    # Collect data until socket closes.
    # Any size can be used in recv() with this protocol.
    cCode = b''
    while True:
        data = cSocket.recv(2048)
        if not data: break
        cCode += data

    print('The color code of the sent image is: ' + cCode.decode())
```

**server.py**

```
import socket
from PIL import Image
import io

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5000

with socket.socket() as sSocket:
    sSocket.bind((IP,PORT))
    sSocket.listen(1)
    print ('The server is ready')
    while True:
        connectionSocket, addr = sSocket.accept()
        with connectionSocket:

            # Collect data until the client shuts down writing.
            # This protocol works with any size in recv()
            img = b''
            while True:
                data = connectionSocket.recv(2048)
                if not data:
                    break
                img += data
            t_img = io.BytesIO(img)
            img = Image.open(t_img)
            cCode = img.getcolors(256)
            cCode = str(cCode)
            print (cCode)
            connectionSocket.sendall(cCode.encode())
```